# operar matrices desde dos archivos txt diferentes

Tags: c++, visual-c++

¡Hola! Buen día:) Quiero realizar un programa (en Visual C++) que haga diversas operaciones (con operadores sobrecargados) con dos matrices leídas desde dos archivos txt diferentes. Hasta el momento he hecho ésto.

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
class matriz {
private:
    uint nFilas, nColumnas;
    float **elementos;
public:
    matriz(const char*);
    void imprimir(const char*);
};

#include "matriz.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<iomanip>

matriz::matriz(const char*archivo) {
    ifstream fcin(archivo, ios::in);
    if (!fcin) {
        cerr << "\nError: El archivo no se pudo abrir\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fcin >> nFilas;
    fcin >> nColumnas;
    elementos = new float*[nFilas];
    for (uint i = 0; i < nFilas; i++) {
        elementos[i] = new float[nColumnas];
        for (uint j = 0; j < nColumnas; j++)
            fcin >> elementos[i][j];
    }

    fcin.close();
}

void matriz::imprimir(const char*archivo) {
    ofstream fcout(archivo, ios::out);
    if (!fcout) {
        cerr << "\nError: El archivo no se pudo abrir\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fcout << nFilas;
    fcout << "\n";
    fcout << nColumnas;
    fcout << "\n";
    for (uint i = 0; i < nFilas; i++) {
        for (uint j = 0; j < nColumnas; j++)
            fcout << setw(6) << elementos[i][j];
        fcout << "\n";
    }
    fcout.close();
};

#include "matriz.h"
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    matriz A("matriz1.txt");
    A.imprimir("matriz2.txt");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comencé realizando el programa con matrices generadas aleatoriamente, y sé realizar las operaciones (suma, resta, multiplicación) con los operadores sobrecargados; y también las operaciones inversa y multiplicación por un escalar.
Sin embargo, al trabajar con matrices leídas desde dos archivos diferentes me complico:\ y tengo varias dudas, iniciando con, ¿cuál es el prototipo para sobrecarga de operadores para matrices desde archivos txt?

Cuando hacía la suma para matrices generadas aleatoriamente, había hecho ésto:

```
matriz* operator+ (const matriz&matriz2){
        matriz*suma=new matriz(nFilas, nColumnas);
        for (uint i=0; i<nFilas; i++){
            for (uint j=0; j<nColumnas; j++){
            suma->elementos[i][j]=elementos[i][j]+matriz2.elementos[i][j];
            }
        }
        return suma;
    }
```

Y de forma similar había realizado las operaciones mencionadas anteriormente y funcionaban bien. Peero, no tengo idea de cómo hacer las operaciones (con sobrecarga) con matrices obtenidas de dos archivos de texto diferentes. 
¿Pueden orientarme, por favor? Ayúdenme por favor, guíenme:( ¡Muchas gracias! Espero haya quedado de forma clara mi duda.

Comment: El problema esta en la lectura de datos? Porque de donde vengan las matrices es indiferente a la hora de calcular

Comment: @ElPatrón ¡hola:)! Sí, ¿cómo sería?  O sea que aunque vengan de archivos txt la definción de la función suma (y las demás que no publiqué) permanecen igual? o en qué cambian? Gracias!

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade el código que permite recuperar los datos de un fichero ya que todo apunta a que el problema está ahí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, si lo que quieres es leer dos matrices distintas lo ideal es que sean objetos distintos.
Para ello se sobrecargará el operador de entrada `>>` de la siguiente manera:

```
istream& operator >> (istream &ent, matriz &m)
{
    ent >> m.nFilas;
    ent >> m.nColumnas;
    m.elementos = new float*[m.nFilas];

    for (uint i = 0; i < m.nFilas; i++) {
        m.elementos[i] = new float[m.nColumnas];
        for (uint j = 0; j < m.nColumnas; j++)
            ent >> m.elementos[i][j];
    }

    return ent ;
}
```

Declarando previamente su cabecera como `friend` en `matriz.h`:

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream &i, matriz &m) ;
```

El resto de comprobaciones pre lectura es más conveniente realizarlas en el main (apertura de ficheros y demás). Como comprobarás a continuación, todo ahora es mucho más estético

```
ifstream fcin("matriz1.txt", ios::in);
if (!fcin) {
    cerr << "\nError: El archivo 1 no se pudo abrir\n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
matriz A ;
fcin >> A ;
```

Una vez leidas las matrices, se pasa a operar con ellas. En tu caso por lo que veo ya tienes implementada la suma, por medio de una sobrecarga.

```
Res = A + B ;
```

Por último, queda guardar el contenido de la matriz resultado en otro fichero distinto. Para ello se sobrecarga el operador de salida `<<`:

```
ostream &operator << (ostream &out,const matriz &m)
{
    out << m.nFilas;
    out << "\n";
    out << m.nColumnas;
    out << "\n";
    for (uint i = 0; i < m.nFilas; i++) {
        for (uint j = 0; j < m.nColumnas; j++)
            out << setw(6) << m.elementos[i][j];
        out << "\n";
    }
    return out ;
}
```

Y, de forma parecida a la anterior, se abre el fichero en el main y se escriben los resultados.

```
ofstream fcout("resultado.txt", ios::out);
if (!fcout) {
    cerr << "\nError: El archivo 3 no se pudo abrir\n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

matriz A, B, Res;
fcin >> A ;
fcin2 >> B ;
Res = A + B ;
fcout << Res ;
```

Espero que con esto ya tengas idea de cómo hacer las operaciones (con sobrecarga) con matrices obtenidas de dos archivos de texto diferentes. 
Te dejo, además, el código completo aquí [matriz](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B76oI9gyAT-naTJ6S0FmV3JOWlU)

Un saludo.